# Using xjc's -enableIntrospection with jaxws-maven-plugin

Tags: java, jaxb, maven, jax-ws

Having run into http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-131, we are trying to adopt the cure provided in its comments, which is to supply -enableIntrospection on xjc's command line.

However, when I do:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>allservice</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <xjcArgs><xjcArg>-enableIntrospection</xjcArg></xjcArgs>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <wsdlDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                        <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/bindings</bindingDirectory>
                        <target>2.0</target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

The maven build fails with:

```
[DEBUG] The binding Directory is C:\Source\workspace\TheProject\src\main\resources\bindings
[DEBUG] jaxws:wsimport args: [-s, C:\Source\workspace\TheProject\target\jaxws\wsimport\java, -d, C:\Source\workspace\TheProject\target\classes, -target, 2.0, -extension, -Xnocompile, -B-enableIntrospection, -b, C:\Source\workspace\TheProject\src\main\resources\bindings\servicebindings.xml]
[INFO] jaxws:wsimport args: [-s, C:\Source\workspace\TheProject\target\jaxws\wsimport\java, -d, C:\Source\workspace\TheProject\target\classes, -target, 2.0, -extension, -Xnocompile, -B-enableIntrospection, -b, C:\Source\workspace\TheProject\src\main\resources\bindings\servicebindings.xml, C:\Source\workspace\TheProject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\wsdl\CaseService.wsdl]
no such JAXB option: -enableIntrospection
```

How can I use xjc's -enableIntrospection with jaxws-maven-plugin? If I can't, what alternatives exist to customize jaxws's code generation so that the getter for a `Boolean` property is called `getFoo()` (correct) rather than `isFoo()` (which violates the Java Beans spec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the jaxws-maven-plugin uses the xjc from the installed JDK. The newest Oracle JDK still contains a version of XJC before support for -enableIntrospection was added.

I next looked into using a JAXB-Plugin. It [turns](http://metro.1045641.n5.nabble.com/Incorporating-JAXB2-Commons-with-jaxws-maven-plugin-td1062209.html#a2800028) [out](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/customizing_jaxb_artifacts#Plugin) that the jaxws-maven-plugin offers no easy way to append to the classpath of XJC, which is required to load JAXB-Plugins.

Replacing the jaxws-maven-plugin was not possible for political reasons (something like "jaxws is the standard, only standard libraries may be used").

I have therefore fallen back to writing a maven plugin that reads the source code after generation, does

```
content.replace("public Boolean is", "public Boolean get");
```

and writes the source file back to disk. That has also allowed me to inject definitions of `equals()` and `hashCode()` that rely on the naming convention for business keys in the API I am consuming.

Answer (score 2):

Add getters for Booleans to the JAX-WS generated artifacts, instead of using the enableIntrospection option and the Java endorsed override mechanism.

Only JAX-WS RI 2.1.13 supports the option enableIntrospection. But JavaSE6 1.6.0_65 ships with JAVA-WS RI 2.1.6. One way to fix this is to use the Java endorsed override mechanism, to copy jaxws-api.jar and jaxb-api.jar into JRE/JDK endorsed directory.

Another way is not to use the enableIntrospection option, but to add getters for Booleans to the JAX-WS generated artifacts. These getters can be added with the replacer maven plugin.

Maven replacer plugin to add a get method:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <basedir>${project.basedir}</basedir>
        <includes>
            <include>src/main/java/lu/etat/cie/rn/rpp/ws/**/*.java</include>
        </includes>
        <token>public Boolean is(.*)\(\)(\s*\{\s*.+\s*\})</token>
        <value>public Boolean is$1\(\)$2
    public Boolean get$1\(\)$2</value>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Replaces:

```
public Boolean isProperty() {
    return property;
}
```

With:

```
public Boolean isProperty() {
    return property;
}
public Boolean getProperty() {
    return property;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<enableIntrospection>true</enableIntrospection>
```

in `<configuration>`
also I can find:

```
<args>
   <arg>-enableIntrospection</arg>
</args>
```

in

```
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.14.0</version>
```